How to set rusflags env var from build script?
I am trying to set an env far from a build.rs script, like this:
fn main()
{
    std::env::set_var("RUSTFLAGS", "-C link-args=-Wl,-rpath,.");
    println!("cargo:rustc-env=RUSTFLAGS=\"-C link-args=-Wl,-rpath,.\"");
    // RUSTFLAGS="-C link-args=-Wl,-rpath,."
    for (key, value) in std::env::vars()
    {
        println!("{}", format!("cargo:warning={} {}", key, value));
    }
}

Which is yielding the output:
...
warning: Demiurge@0.1.0: QT_IM_MODULE ibus
warning: Demiurge@0.1.0: RUSTC /home/makogan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-01-08-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc
warning: Demiurge@0.1.0: RUSTDOC /home/makogan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-01-08-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustdoc
warning: Demiurge@0.1.0: RUSTUP_HOME /home/makogan/.rustup
warning: Demiurge@0.1.0: RUSTUP_TOOLCHAIN nightly-2024-01-08-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
warning: Demiurge@0.1.0: RUST_RECURSION_COUNT 1
warning: Demiurge@0.1.0: SESSION_MANAGER local/makogan-kingdom:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/3901,unix/makogan-kingdom:/tmp/.ICE-unix/3901
warning: Demiurge@0.1.0: SHELL /bin/bash
...

As you can see, no rustflags. I also tried setting project_root/.cargo/config.toml to this:
[env]
RUSTFLAGS= { value = "-C link-args=-Wl,-rpath,.", force = true, relative = true }

[build]
rustflags = ["-C", "link-args=-Wl,-rpath-link,./"]

Still nothing, how do I set the flags? if I just do export RUSTFLAGS="-C link-args=-Wl,-rpath,." before calling cargo it works how I expect it to.

-rpath and -rpath-link are different options, which one do you mean? Also relative = true means "Value is relative to .cargo directory containing config.toml" i.e. your_project/.cargo I don't think that's what you mean⁉

And also probably should emit cargo::rustc-link-arg=FLAG instead of going the detour through RUSTFLAGS

The documentation of "link-args" specifies "This flag lets you append multiple extra arguments to the linker invocation. The options should be separated by spaces." you seem to be using commas instead

The second option was the one that worked for me, by adding it in build.rs

Unrelated but println!("{}", format!("cargo:warning={} {}", key, value)); is better written println!("cargo:warning={} {}", key, value);

Does this answer your question? How can I specify linker flags/arguments in a build script?
